# Clicking Comment Button on Youtube

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to make a `vb.net` program that automatically comments on a video. So far I've got:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZZquVylLEo")
    End Sub
```

Now I need to make it click the comment box on the site. I thought the way to do this would be -

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(".comment-simplebox-renderer-collapsed-content").InvokeMember("click")
End Sub
```

But that just gives an error. I'm really lost on how to do this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's really important to read[ask] .. please include all the details. What error? If you dont put the effort in, we are less likely to.

Comment: HttpWebRequest is the best way to do what you want. I really don't prefer WebBrowser for such situations.

Comment: I don't think youtube would be happy with that. They offer an API to do just that.

Comment: I have nothing to say about the question but damn bro thanks for introducing me to the that video. made my day

Answer (score 0):

Add a webbrowser to a project and name it "browser"

```
  browser.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ4oaLUilBc")
    While browser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    Dim comment_wrote As Boolean = False
    Dim comment_done As Boolean = False
    While comment_wrote = False
        For Each altelm As HtmlElement In browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("DIV")
            If altelm.GetAttribute("classname").ToString = "comment-simplebox-renderer-collapsed comment-simplebox-trigger" Then
                altelm.Focus()
                altelm.InvokeMember("click")
            End If

            If altelm.GetAttribute("classname").ToString = "comment-simplebox-text" And comment_wrote = False Then
                altelm.Focus()
                altelm.InvokeMember("click")
                SendKeys.SendWait("I love this song!")
                comment_wrote = True
            End If

        Next
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    While comment_done = False
        For Each altelm As HtmlElement In browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON")
            If altelm.GetAttribute("classname").ToString = "yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-primary yt-uix-button-empty comment-simplebox-submit yt-uix-sessionlink" And comment_done = False Then
                altelm.Focus()
                altelm.InvokeMember("click")
                comment_done = True
            End If
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
```